# Window.onload scope issues

Tags: javascript

So I have been trying to create a function that can collect push all the data in `this.courses` into a table body with my `FetchAll` property, but for some reason I keep on getting this error in my `FetchAll` function in the `window.onload`:

> cannot set innerHTML of undefined

However, when I don't use `window.onload` and place `app.FetchAll()` outside of the app scope, running the script at the bottom of the body, I have full access to `this.el`.

What's going on here?

```
var app = new function () {
  // code

  //we want to get each course by its id
  this.el = document.getElementById('courses');


  //this is all of our data in an array.
  this.courses=['Biology', 'Chemistry','History','English','Spanish','Geography'];

  //now we want to make the count function

  this.Count = function (data) {
    //the data is the input for waht we wanto count
    var el = document.getElementById('courses');
    var name = 'courses';

    if (data) {
      if (data > 1) {
        // sets the name var to courses
        name = 'courses';
      }
      el.innerHTML = data + '' + name;
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = 'No' + name;
    }
  }

  this.FetchAll = function () {
    var data = ''; // this is what we are going to put the html into
    if (this.courses.length > 0)   {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.courses.length; i++) {
          data += '<tr>';
          data += '<td>' + this.courses[i] + '</td>';
          data += '</tr>';
        }
    }
    this.Count(this.courses.length);
    return this.el.innerHTML = data;

  };

  this.Add = function (data) {

    alert("add something")
  }

}

window.onload = function () {
  app.FetchAll();

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's undefined instead of null? This sounds like you are not calling your method with the desired `this`, but in the code you posted it should work.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a *scope* issue, it's just a matter of when things happen as the browser interprets the HTML document. Your initialization code that creates the `app` object runs before the browser has built the DOM. Because of that, the `.getElementById()` call is returning `null`.

It works when you move the code to the end of the `<body>` because when the code runs in that case the DOM is (mostly) constructed.

The placement of the call to `FetchAll()` can be in the "load" handler or not if your code is at the bottom. If you put *all* the code (including the construction of the `app` object) into the "load" handler, that would also work.

Comment: But the question says it is undefined, not null

Comment: @Oriol well that sure is true. hmm